# Можно ли делать исключения на не английском?

Tags: python

Можно ли использовать не английские сообщения для исключений, причин и вообще любых полях, кроме комментариев, в каком-то относительно большом и многогранном проекте?

Насколько хорошо/плохо (с точки зрения культуры) написать `raise ValueError('n должно быть целым')` 
вместо `raise ValueError('n must be integer')`?

С точки зрения культуры и т.д. Допустим, что этот условный проект не интернациональный, программируют преимущественно русские люди

Comment: Да, можно. Но исключения никогда не являются частью пользовательского интерфейса. Иначе говоря, если программа нормально написана, пользователь не увидит исключение, а увидит сообщение об ошибке. А раз так, то формируйте исключение так чтобы вам самому (при отладке) или вашей программе (при нормальной работе) было удобно его обрабатывать.

Comment: Если хотите загнать русских в резервацию, то это стоящая идея

Comment: @avp Если проект целиком русскоязычный, то использование сообщений в гите в комментариях на английском - карго-культ из-за которого никакого выигрыша, кроме практики в английском. Зато минусы в потере смыслов, т.к. на родном языке легче понять друг друга.

Comment: @Alpensin, общаясь на родном языке вы навсегда погрязнете в  болоте местных смыслов

Comment: только у одного программиста сущность называется  way, у другого route. путь(путевой лист) по русски вроде way. но автомобиль выходит на маршрут, а на на путь) потом потом если закопаться в делопроизводство - как по английски отличить сальдо от баланса....

Comment: а ещё переменные можно по русски называть. только не удобно переключать раскладку под операторы...

Comment: @avp Мы говорим о работе с документацией конкретного проекта и языке в тексте исключений. Ничто не мешает параллельно общаться и изучать материалы всего мира.

Answer (score 7):

То что написано в скобках - это всего лишь текст. Он должен быть понятен тому кто его увидит. А увидеть его должны только если исключение не обработано - сервис или программа упали. В некоторых случаях не очень удобно когда падает в системе где не настроен русский шрифт.

Приведу примеры: `gcc` и `postgresql` показывают исключения на русском языке. И это **не очень удобно** "гуглить", но если ошибка знакома - то понять её проще.

psql

```
postgres=# select * from ;
ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: ";")
СТРОКА 1: select * from ;
                        ^
```

и gcc

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.1/../../../../lib/Scrt1.o: в функции «_start»:
(.text+0x1b): неопределённая ссылка на «main»
collect2: ошибка: выполнение ld завершилось с кодом возврата 1
```

А ещё можно переменные называть кириллицей, но не нужно. Старшие ругаться будут.

```
>>> ы=1
>>> ы
1
```

Comment: *"не очень не удобно"* кажется у вас тут одно *"не"* лишнее.

Comment: Вы написали настолько обтекаемый ответ, что его положительно воспринимают обе стороны. Для полноты картины стоило бы еще добавить, что язык, на котором gcc и psql выводят сообщения определяется текущей локалью, которую всегда можно переустановить (т.е. текст сообщений не зашит в исходный код этих приложений)

Comment: просто описал свое впечатление. А вот с переводами я считаю вопрос отдельный: По мне надо писать  на родном, а потом переводить на английский. но всё зависит от целей приложения..